# After recompiling vim to use python 3, I still get "requires Vim compiled with Python 2.x support" from YCM

Tags: python3, vim

I followed the instructions at https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source which included adding python3 support.  Then I installed ycm per the instructions at https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Full-Installation-Guide.

And it still complains with "YouCompleteMe unavailable: requires Vim compiled with Python 2.x support"

Since the instructions to add Python 3 came from the ycm-core, I would think that somehow ycm knows to use it.  But no.

So did I miss a step?

Comment: Avoid rebuilding Vim from source. (It's a terrible advice from YCM!!!) You won't get updates and security fixes and eventually your build will go stale. Instead, just install a more featured Vim package in Ubuntu, such as vim-gtk3 or vim-nox, which should include support for all the features you care about.

Answer (score 1):

I apparently used outdated instructions.  The vim install was good, but the YCM install instructions were old.

What I did was remove the directory .vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/ completely and add 
.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/
To the proper place in .vimrc, then run

:PluginInstall from within vim.

Then I went to .vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe and ran

python3 install.py

The previous instructions didn't provide a install.py file.

Jim